# How do i display & style JSON data in my HTML (via node JS/Express) page

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Slowly losing my sanity with this. Hope someone can help :)

I am trying to:

1. pull my JSON data
2. link to it in my javascript
3. display it in a half-decent way on my index html page.

I have created a mock-up - my questions are:

If i run this - it doesn't change the HTML to the JSON data. Any of it. So i have no hope of then drilling down into it further to actually get to, say, "Peter" - Am i missing a step? Is there a reason i can't change `getElementByID` element to JSON data?

If i *do* just want to style/display information contained in a JSON, grabbed from an API - how is best to do that?

```
HTML
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <p id="pastehere" onclick="jsonFunction ()"></p>
</body>

JS (using node)
var express = require('express');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var data = require('data.json');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendfile('index.html');
});

app.listen(3000);

function jsonfunction () {
document.getElementByID("pastehere").innerHTML = data;
}
```

JSON

```
{
"person": [
   {
       "firstName": "Clark",
       "lastName": "Kent",
       "job": "Reporter",
       "roll": 20
   },
   {
       "firstName": "Bruce",
       "lastName": "Wayne",
       "job": "Playboy",
       "roll": 30
   },
   {
       "firstName": "Peter",
       "lastName": "Parker",
       "job": "Photographer",
       "roll": 40
   }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Why don't you <pre> tag to display the json ? Or you can even try textarea in non-editable mode. To format the json you can do something like : `JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)`

Comment: And to get data from server you need to first have an API implemented on server say `/data` which will respond with the desired json data. On client you can use ajax to call the API and get the response.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/prettyprint-for-javascript/? I love it.